# Not successfully updating multiple records with extjs (500-error)

Tags: extjs

The application is developed with extjs 4 and ext scheduler.
I want to select a number of records and update these, the records are updated but to many update-request are posted (i use json).

For example i want to edit two records, two POST requests to update are posted, the first gets status 200 and the other one gets status 500 (internal server error).
The first post are much smaller in size then the last one (1.9 KB versus 9.2 KB in this case)

```
onSaveClick: function () {
var selectedEvents = grids.scheduler.getEventSelectionModel().getSelection();


            stores.eventStore.suspendAutoSync();
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedEvents.length; i++) {
                selectedEvents[i].set({
                    CustomerId: variables.customerField.getValue(),
                    CustomerName: variables.customerField.getRawValue(),
                    Notes: variables.hideFieldsField.getComponent('Notes').getValue(),
                    Scope: variables.scopeField.getValue().Scope,
                    Preliminary: variables.preliminaryBox.getValue(),
                    WorkWeekends: variables.weekendsField.getValue()
                });

            stores.eventStore.resumeAutoSync();
            stores.eventStore.sync();
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I solved it by adding selectedEvents[i].commit();